# Uncaught TypeError using Javascript

Tags: typeerror

I'm getting errors for undefined stuff even though it's defined. I have say a function that calls update() from imported functions to no avail. It just says it's undefined.

Like I'll pack all of the sound effects nice and neat into a file with a class called SoundEffects and import that class in ClickEvents class and then in ClickEvents I say this.sounds = new Sounds(). But when I use the ClickEvents class update() to call sounds.update() it says that it's undefined. What gives?

```
import { Sounds } from './sounds.js';
import { DisplayText } from './displayText.js';

export class ClickEvents {
    constructor(game) {
        this.game = game;
        this.sounds = new Sounds(this);
        this.displayText = new DisplayText(this);
        this.numClicks = 0;
        this.doOnce = false;
        this.currentCamera = document.getElementById("currentCamera");

        this.pickles = false;
        this.doOnce = false;
    }
    update(toSetup, messages, startButtonPressed, clickables) {

        if (startButtonPressed && !this.doOnce) {
            this.doOnce = true;
            for (let i = 0; i < clickables.length; i++) {
                let self = clickables[i];
                self.addEventListener('click', handler, true);
                function handler(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (this.numClicks === 1)
                        return false;
                    this.numClicks += 1;
                    if (this.id === 'doorZone1') {
                        toSetup.innerText = 'toSet';
                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_00') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_01';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_01') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_00';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_02') {
                            if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_02') {
                                if (!this.frontDoorClicked) {
                                    this.sounds.update(1, 1.0); //door locked sound
                                    this.displayText.update(messages[8], 1000, this.numClicks); //MESSAGE: "The door is locked"
                                    this.frontDoorClicked = true;
                                } else {
                                    this.displayText.update(messages[9], 3000, this.numClicks); //FBI, open up!!
                                    this.frontDoorClicked = false;
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_03') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_01';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_04') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_05';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_05') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_06';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_06') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_05';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_07') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_02';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_08') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_07';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_09') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_08';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_10') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_09';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_12') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_05';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        }


                    } else if (this.id === 'doorZone2') {
                        toSetup.innerText = 'toSet';
                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_01') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_02';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_02') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_07';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_03') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_12';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_04') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_01';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_05') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_12';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_06') {
                            this.sounds.update(1, 1.0); //door locked sound
                            this.displayText.update(messages[7], 1000, this.numClicks); //MESSAGE: "The door is locked"
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_07') {
                            this.sounds.update(1, 1.0); //door locked sound
                            this.displayText.update(messages[5], 1000, this.numClicks); //MESSAGE: "The door is locked"
                            //after x amount of time a dog barks
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.sounds.update(5, 1.0); //dog barking sound
                            }, 1250);
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_08') {
                            this.sounds.update(1, 1.0); //door locked sound
                            this.displayText.update(messages[6], 1000, this.numClicks); //MESSAGE: "The door is locked"
                            //after x amount of time a dog barks
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.sounds.update(5, 1.0); //dog barking sound
                            }, 1250);
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_09') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_10';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_10') {
                            //play scrolling effect
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_11';
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_12') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_03';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        }

                    } else if (this.id === 'doorZone3') {
                        toSetup.innerText = 'toSet';
                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_01') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_03';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_02') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_01';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_05') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_04';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_07') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_08';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_08') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_09';
                            this.sounds.update(2, 0.5); //metal ladder sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        }

                    } else if (this.id === 'doorZone4') {
                        toSetup.innerText = 'toSet';
                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_01') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_04';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        } else if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_07') {
                            this.currentCamera.innerText = 'ROOM_108_08';
                            this.sounds.update(3, 0.5); //wet footstep sound
                            this.numClicks = 0;
                        }

                        //events to handle when message zones are clicked
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone1') {

                        //says that displayText is undefined and displayText() is not a function
                        console.log(this.displayText());
                        this.displayText.update(messages[0], 3000, this.numClicks);


                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_03')
                            this.sounds.update(4, 1.0); //tall P laugh sound
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone2') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[1], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone3') {
                        if (this.currentCamera.innerText === 'ROOM_108_06')
                            this.displayText.update(messages[2], 4500, this.numClicks);
                        else
                            this.displayText.update(messages[2], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone4') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[3], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone5') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[4], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone6') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[5], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone7') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[6], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone8') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[7], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone9') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[8], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone10') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[9], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone11') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[10], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    } else if (this.id === 'msgZone12') {
                        this.displayText.update(messages[11], 3000, this.numClicks);
                    }//else if
                }//function handler(e) {
            } //for()
        } //if(startButtonPressed)
    }//update()
}//class ClickEvents
```

Comment: Well Justin it looks like your code goes out of scope when it enters function handler(e); it reads before then but not after